# The difference between output return and print_r

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is a controller in codeigniter, i have problem in return on function `get_reunits()` when run function `marge_orderfun()`. when i run function `get_reunits()` with print_r in output(`print_r($hotel_data);`) i give following output(it is what that i want):

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
[name] => 11
[price] => 77192276
[extra] => 11
[hotel_id] => 77192276
)
[1] => Array (
[name] => 11
[price] => 77192276
[extra] => 11
[hotel_id] => 77192276
)
) Array (
[0] => Array (
[name] => 666666666
[price] => 15190364
[extra] => 11
[hotel_id] => 15190364
)
[1] => Array (
[name] => 99999
[price] => 15190364
[extra] => 11
[hotel_id] => 15190364
)
[2] => Array (
[name] => 777777
[price] => 15190364
[extra] => 11
[hotel_id] => 15190364
)
[3] => Array (
[name] => 1221
[price] => 15190364
[extra] => 11
[hotel_id] => 15190364
)
) Array (
[0] => Array (
[name] => 666666666
[price] => 11
[extra] => 33
[hotel_id] => 15183965
)
[1] => Array (
[name] => 99999
[price] => 11
[extra] => 33
[hotel_id] => 15183965
)
[2] => Array (
[name] => 777777
[price] => 11
[extra] => 33
[hotel_id] => 15183965
)
[3] => Array (
[name] => 1221
[price] => 11
[extra] => 33
[hotel_id] => 15183965
)
)
```

When use from `return $hotel_data;` for output and run function `marge_orderfun()` i get this output:

> {"reunits":[{"name":"11","price":"77192276","extra":"11","hotel_id":"77192276"},{"name":"11","price":"77192276","extra":"11","hotel_id":"77192276"}]}

This is my controller:

```
function get_reunits(){
    //$tourf_id   = $this->input->post('tour_name');
    $tourf_id = '102';
    $query_r = $this->db->order_by('id','desc')->get_where('tour_foreign_residence', array('relation' => $tourf_id));                
    foreach($query_r->result() as $idx=>$val){
        $hotel_id = $val->hotel_id;
        $query = $this->db->get_where('tour_foreign_units', array('hotel_id' => $hotel_id));
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            $hotel_data = array();
            foreach ($query->result() as $index=>$row) {
                $hotel_data[] = array(
                    'name' => $row->name,
                    'price' => $row->price,
                    'extra' => $row->extra,
                    'hotel_id' => $row->hotel_id
                );                            
            }
        }else{
                return 0;
        }
        //print_r($hotel_data);
        return $hotel_data;
    }
}
function marge_orderfun(){
    //$guide = array('guide' => $this->get_gr());
    //$residence = array('residence' => $this->get_residence());
    $reunits = array('reunits' => $this->get_reunits());
    echo json_encode(array_merge(/*$guide, $residence,*/$reunits));
}
```

What do i do for a output in `marge_orderfun()` as output in print_r in `get_reunits()`?

Comment: Instead of `echo json_encode`, use `printr`? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Json send to ajax call in jquery.

Comment: So why do you need output which looks like `print_r`?

Answer (score 1):

You're outputting two different things, actually. print_r is dumping out the structure/contents of a PHP array in a nicely readable format. your marge_orderfun is dump out a string of text which happens to be in JSON format. This json string USED to be a PHP array, but now it's just a blob of text.

Comment: what do i do, for has output like print_r?(how is it in my code)

Comment: `print_r(array_merge(...))` instead of `echo json_encode(array_merge(...))`

Comment: I send output with json to ajax call, do with print_r can get output in ajax call?

Comment: Sure, but remember that your javascript will be expecting JSON output. if it gets print_r output, it's going to complain. What are you trying to do with this? print_r output is for debugging, and was never intended to be a transport format like JSON.

Comment: I use from `print_r(array_merge(...))` and get this output: `Array ( [guide] => 0 [residence] => 0 [reunits] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => 11 [price] => 77192276 [extra] => 11 [hotel_id] => 77192276 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => 11 [price] => 77192276 [extra] => 11 [hotel_id] => 77192276 ) ) ) 1` what do i do?

Comment: How can I answer that? I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code helps:

```
$a = array();
$b = print_r($a, true);
echo $b;
```